# Why do i get same text in both Pop-ups using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using OpenLLayers 5. I saved Longitude, Latitude and car name in an array from the Database. I could display two Markers(My Array has just two indexes for the moment). Each Marker has a Pop-up window which should contain its name, longitude, latitude. For Example first Marker's Pop-up has car 1 as a text. The car name is vehName in my case.
I am always getting the Informations of the second car(which is the last index of my Array) displayed on both Pop-ups.
Could anyone please help me find out a solution for this?

```
/* open street map newest version */
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map', // the div id
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({ 
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.35247, 52.520008]),
        zoom: 6,
        minZoom: 3
    })
});
for(var i=0; i < arrayPos.length; i++) {
    var long = arrayPos[i][0]
    var lat = arrayPos[i][1];
    var vehName = arrayPos[i][2];
    var batterCharge = arrayPos[i][3];
    console.log(batterCharge);
    // add a marker to the map
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat]))
                })  
            ]
        })
    });
    layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/0/0c/Hgv.png', //
        scale: 0.4 // set the size of the vehicle on the map
        })
    }));
    map.addLayer(layer);
    //initialize the popup
    var container = document.getElementById('popup');
    var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: true,
        autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 250
        }
    });
    map.addOverlay(overlay);

    //display the pop with on mouse over event
    map.on('pointermove', function (event) {
        if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {  
            var coordinate = event.coordinate;
            //simple text written in the popup, values are just of the second index
            content.innerHTML = vehName+'<br><b>Batteriestatus: </b>'+batterCharge;//just the second one is getting displayed
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        else {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        }
    });
}
```

Edited version!
Still not working though!
any ideas?

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayPos.length; i++) {
    //infos
    var long = arrayPos[i][0]
    var lat = arrayPos[i][1];
    var vehName = arrayPos[i][2];
    var batteryCharge = arrayPos[i][3];
    
    //create a feature
    var feature = new new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat]))
    })
    feature.set('batteryCharge', batteryCharge);
    vectorSource.add(feature);
}   
// add a marker to the map
var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorSource();
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource({
        features: [feature]
    })
});

layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/0/0c/Hgv.png', //
    scale: 0.4 // set the size of the vehicle on the map
    })
}));
map.addLayer(layer);

//initialize the popup
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

//display the pop with on mouse over event
map.on('pointermove', function (event) {
    if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {  
        var coordinate = event.coordinate;
        const features = event.target.getFeatures();
        const batteryCharge  = features.get(0).get('batteryCharge');

        //simple text written in the popup, values are just of the second index
        content.innerHTML = event.traget+'<br><b>Batteriestatus: </b>'+batteryCharge;
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    }
    else {
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Christoph, can you please take a look at this?, did I miss something here ?

Comment: You need to create  the vectorSoure  as a variable as well:
var  vectorSource  = new ol.source.VectorSource()  
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource)}

Comment: @ChristophS Yep you're right i edited it again. I am sorry, I got really no experience with Maps yet. I am still getting nothing displayed on the Map :(( and i cant see something i've missed to write..

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and overwriting your layer and overlay in the loop.
Normally, you create the Vector Layer and the Vector Source outside of a loop and then in the loop where you are creating your features, you just simply add them to the vectorSource.
And you should also store your battery charge info etc as property in the feature so you can acess them with event.target.
And you can also use [forEachFeatureAtPixel](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch08-interacting-with-your-map/example-03.html)

Edit://  Here is an example how the for loop could look like.
Source is the vectorSource also declared outside

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayPos.length; i++) {
    const long = arrayPos[i][0]
    const lat = arrayPos[i][1];
    const vehName = arrayPos[i][2];
    const batterCharge = arrayPos[i][3];
    console.log(batterCharge);
    
    var feature = new new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat]))
    }) 
    feature.set('batteryCharge', batterCharge)
    source.add(feature)

}
```

And your event:

```
  //display the pop with on mouse over event
    map.on('pointermove', function (event) {
        if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {  
            var coordinate = event.coordinate;
            const features = event.target.getFeatures()
            const batterCharge  = features.get(0).get('batteryCharge')
            //simple text written in the popup, values are just of the second index
            content.innerHTML = event.traget+'<br><b>Batteriestatus: </b>'+batterCharge;//just the second one is getting displayed
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        else {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get the idea, but i am really a little bit newbie to OpenLayers, i have tried to edit the code as you said but it didnt change it. Could you please edit the code? because the Link you mentioned is also a way far from the code i wrote. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if i create the Vector Layer and the Vector Source outside of the loop, i cant save the long and the lat values in the Geometry they wont be accessible?

Comment: I added some example code. You should be able to figure out the rest.
The idea is just add the feature creation to the loop.

Comment: I added my Answer, could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors in the posted code.

1. The first error I get with your code is `Uncaught ReferenceError: arrayPos is not defined` (because it isn't).
2. When I add that array, I get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a constructor` on this line:

   ```
   var feature = new new ol.Feature({
   ```

   (extra `new`)
3. When I remove the extra `new`, I get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` on this line:

   ```
   vectorSource.add(feature);
   ```

   because `vectorSource` is not yet defined.
4. When I move the definition up above that line, I get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: ol.source.VectorSource is not a constructor` (because with `ol.js` that should be `ol.source.Vector`).
5. When I fix that, I get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: vectorSource.add is not a function` (because it isn't a function, that should be `addFeature`).
6. When I fix that, I get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: vectorSource is not a function` on these lines:

   ```
   source: vectorSource({
      features: [feature]
   })
   ```

   (because it isn't, that should be the variable `vectorSource` that you added the markers to)

Now I get markers on the map, but still get a syntax error: `Uncaught TypeError: event.target.getFeatures is not a function`

You aren't using @Mike's code from your other question: [Display Multiple Markers on OpenLayers 5 dynamically with Pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445791/display-multiple-markers-on-openlayers-5-dynamically-with-pop-up-window):

```
const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
if (features.length > 0) {
    var coordinate = event.coordinate;
    const batteryCharge = features[0].get('batteryCharge');
```

If I use that, I get popups (with different values) for each marker.

(and "undefined" in the text because: `event.traget` isn't defined.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4b0wjgLv/2/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
/* open street map newest version */
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map', // the div id
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.35247, 52.520008]),
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 3
  })
});
var arrayPos = [
  [1.297355, 52.6308859, 0, "80"],
  [0.121817, 52.205337, 0, "85"]
];
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(); // Source();
for (var i = 0; i < arrayPos.length; i++) {
  //infos
  var long = arrayPos[i][0]
  var lat = arrayPos[i][1];
  var vehName = arrayPos[i][2];
  var batteryCharge = arrayPos[i][3];

  //create a feature
  var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat]))
  })
  feature.set('batteryCharge', batteryCharge);
  vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
}
// add a marker to the map

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/0/0c/Hgv.png', //
    scale: 0.4 // set the size of the vehicle on the map
  })
}));
map.addLayer(layer);

//initialize the popup
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

//display the pop with on mouse over event
map.on('pointermove', function(event) {
  const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
  if (features.length > 0) {
    var coordinate = event.coordinate;
    const batteryCharge = features[0].get('batteryCharge');

    //simple text written in the popup, values are just of the second index
    content.innerHTML = event.traget + '<br><b>Batteriestatus: </b>' + batteryCharge;
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Map popup */

.ol-popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: -50px;
  min-width: 280px;
}

.ol-popup:after,
.ol-popup:before {
  top: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ol-popup:after {
  border-top-color: white;
  border-width: 10px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.ol-popup:before {
  border-top-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 11px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>
```